# How to import a large amount of .bed, .gff, .vcf, .paf, .sam files into an SQL database?

Tags: vcf, database, bed, sam, gff

Are there best practices to load different bioinformatics file formats such as VCF, BED, GFF, and SAM to SQL databases? I am wondering how people out there do that efficiently.

All of these three formats are tab-separated files, so basically the following should work. I feel weird about it since most people I know don't use MySQL to work with these files.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bed.bed'
INTO TABLE bed-file
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS (list of the columns)
SET creation_date  = STR_TO_DATE(@creation_date, '%m/%d/%y');
```

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory answer to this question? I'd love to hear more about what sort of solution, if any, you ended up with.

Comment: @JessimeKirk not really. I've heard recently about [Glow](https://glow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). Maybe it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

The [clodius](https://github.com/higlass/clodius) tool puts tab-delimited data from a BED file into an [rtree](https://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) in a sqlite3 database:

https://github.com/higlass/clodius/blob/c98bb16ade93402fcea3b749d705c52ea165b609/clodius/cli/aggregate.py#L457-L777

Data are stored in this database at multiple "zoom levels", which allows for fast queries at wide genomic extents:

https://github.com/higlass/clodius/blob/develop/clodius/tiles/beddb.py

Aggregation (input) and querying (output) seem efficient in practice, but efficiency may depend on aspects of your specific dataset, i.e., whether you mean efficiency in execution time of `INSERT` or `SELECT` statements, or in space efficiency in the overall database size.

Other data can be converted to BED via `vcf2bed`, `sam2bed`, `gff2bed`, etc. and then aggregated. This is not the only way to do things, of course, but hopefully this can suggest directions to explore.

Answer (score 1):

You might also take a look at this genomics-focused sqlite extension: https://github.com/mlin/GenomicSQLite

As described in the repository README:

> This SQLite3 loadable extension adds features to the ubiquitous
> embedded RDBMS supporting applications in genome bioinformatics:
>
> - genomic range indexing for overlap queries & joins
> - in-SQL utility functions, e.g. reverse-complement DNA, parse "chr1:2,345-6,789"
> - automatic streaming storage compression (also available standalone)
> - reading directly from HTTP(S) URLs (also available standalone)
> - pre-tuned settings for "big data"